# Creating Public Quip Apps

Tags: quip, liveapps

I've created my first Quip App using the [Live Apps API](https://quip.com/dev/liveapps/documentation), building off the [Calendar App](https://github.com/quip/quip-apps/tree/master/examples/calendar) example.

[image: my first Quip app]

I have this running well in my localhost environment, but I can't figure out how I can publish my app and share it with a client.

Can I deploy my app to a publicly available site (e.g. Heroku) so other's can install it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now, you can only develop and share Live Apps within your own site.

However, Quip Live Apps will be integrating with AppExchange very soon, where you will be able to publish your Live App and admins from other sites will be able to discover and install it.

Comment: Who does "we" refer to here?

Comment: Sorry, the Quip Engineering team. Will update the answer to be more clear.